# Can a dodecahedron be deformed into a great stellated dodecahedron?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, polyhedra, polytopes

Can a convex regular dodecahedron be deformed into a great stellated dodecahedron while keeping all pentagons planar and all edges of nonzero length the whole time?

[image]

Comment: If you're like me and don't know what *great stellated dodecahedron* means, this will save you half a second https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_stellated_dodecahedron

Comment: The faces of a dodecahedron are pentagons, but your GSD has triangular facets.  This  means you are using the word "deform" in a manner that is unfamiliar to me.   It seems like you are allowing a polyhedral isotopy, perhaps with arbitrary subdivisions?

Comment: I assume (but perhaps it is better if I state and see if the original poster confirms) that the 5 points which start on a face of the dodecahedron must remain coplanar at all times, but move through non-convex positions until they finally are arranged at the vertices of a 5 pointed star. (This means that, at some times, one of these points must be on the line segment through some of the others.)

Comment: The great stellated dodecahedron’s faces are pentagrammic, not triangular.

Comment: When you say “on the line segment”, do you mean physically between the vertices or anywhere on the same line as them?

Comment: Then isn't your picture wrong? I see a union of triangles. Perhaps the absence of yellow vertices at some intersection points is indicating this isn't an object embedded in $\mathbb R^3$?  Either way, I do not know what "deform" means to you.

Comment: @DanielSebald - physically in between is necessary. By the way - nice question!

Comment: @RyanBudney - here are the rules, as I understand them. Let $D$ be the usual dodecahedron, embedded in space. Consider the set of maps of the one-skeleton of $D$ into three-space so that (i) edges are sent to line segments (of positive length!) and (ii) five-cycles lie in a plane. (That is, for each map and for each five-cycle, there is some plane containing the image of the five-cycle.). We topologise the set as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{60}$.

Comment: Another (equivalent) way to topologise the space is to use the face normals.  This gives us a dimension count of 36; there are 12 faces and each requires three dimensions (unit normal (2) plus offset (1)).

Comment: As a perhaps easier question: using these rules can you invert a cube? (That is, deform it so all of the outward face normals end up pointing inward?)

Comment: Oops! That leads me to a question about the original problem - must the image of a five-cycle always lie in a unique plane? Because, if not, then the “normal vector” coordinates do not work… and also there may be a solution where at one moment all 20 vertices lie in a single line.

Comment: You've changed the question in a serious way. This breaks the answer. I strongly suggest you role back the changes, and ask a new question.  _Furthermore_, the new form of the question makes little sense. What is an "element" and how do we find its dimension? (The charm of your original questions is that we think of the GSD as an _immersion_ of the dodecahedron.)

Comment: @SamNead Associated with the dodecahedron is a face lattice, and Daniel asks for an embedding of the dodecahedron's vertices (resp. a continuous transition between such) so that a set of vertices that corresponds to a $d$-dimensional face in the face lattice has a $d$-dimensional affine hull in the embedding.

Comment: Just in case you make another post, could you make a comment or edit this post to include a link to the new question? I don't want to lose track of this interesting question.

Comment: @M.Winter - Yes... that is a very reasonable interpretation of the original intent. And it is an interesting question!  But I think it should be a _new_ question.

Comment: Here it is: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/402907/dodecahedron-deformation-ii

Comment: @RyanBudney If you can see the "bright" red triangles, they are all supposed to be on the same plane. The shape they make is a pentagram, which is supposed to be a "face" of the great stellated dodecahedron - hence the faces being "pentagrammatic" (rather than pentagonal or triangular).

Comment: That said, I do not understand the "rules" either.

Answer (score 4):

Talking with Saul Schleimer, we came up with the following:

Orthogonally project the great stellated dodecahedron into the $z=0$ plane, choosing a direction that does not result in any zero length edges. Do the same for the dodecahedron.
We can realise each of these projections as the endpoint of a homotopy through affine maps $(x,y,z) \to (x,y,(1-t)z)$, so planarity is preserved.

Now that everything is in the plane, the planarity of faces is easy to maintain. Note that the condition that an edge has length zero is codimension two. Therefore we can move the vertices of the flat dodecahedron to the vertices of the flat great stellated dodecahedron in a generic way.

Comment: Oops. This shouldn’t be allowed, but I didn’t consider this particular case. I’ve edited the question.

Comment: @DanielSebald, editing the question in a way that invalidates existing answers is not generally approved.  Asking another question would probably be better.

Comment: Okay. Good to know.

Comment: Strong agree with LSpice here.  It is not so fun to play a game where the rules change at the whim of just one of the players. :(