# Dodecahedron deformation II

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, polyhedra, polytopes

(Follow-up to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/402784/can-a-dodecahedron-be-deformed-into-a-great-stellated-dodecahedron))

Can a dodecahedron be deformed into a great stellated dodecahedron while maintaining the number of dimensions each element occupies?

[image]

Comment: I did not understand your previous question, and I don't understand the new one either.

Comment: I just want to mention that you basically ask whether the realization space of a certain matroid is connected (or at least whether two specific points belong to the same connected component). I am not an expert for this, but there might be some general theory or some algorithms that you can apply to this problem.

Comment: On the other question's comment thread Sam Nead asked whether you can invert a cube following the same rules. I think the answer is no: take a face F and a vertex V not on that face, then V has to pass the plane spanned by F at some point. When it does, then the two vertices sharing a face with V and two vertices of F must also lie on the same plane. And by the same argument so must the last cube vertex, so the cube is no longer 3-dimensional.

Comment: I think the same argument should rule out a solution in the case of the dodecahedron too. That is, I don't think you can deform the dodcehadron into the GSD without a vertex passing through the plane of a neighboring face.